# Angular - change of property value ignored until output callback ends

Tags: angular, typescript

I have component that should display some spinner while operation takes place:

html:

```
<spinner *ngIf='isLoading'></spinner>
<xx-table
  (onSort)='onSort()'>
</xx-table>
```

Component.ts:

```
onSort(): void {
  this.isLoading = true;
  // operation lasting around 1 second
  this.isLoading = false;
}
```

I have a line that explicitly changes value of `this.isLoading` to true however this change is never detected by the template.

Seems like change detection is triggered only after `onSort()` method is finished - if I remove line `this.isLoading = false;` spinner is shown (and stays there) but after the ~1 second (duration of the operation that takes place)

How to make this change visible while method is still executing? And what exact mechanism is behind this?

(I know I can trigger change detection manually, but why this is not recognized as change?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A block of javascript code will continue executing until it completes, there is only one execution path.  It looks like your code is synchronous and there are no async operations, so control is never returned to angular to update the page while `isLoading` is true.

You can use `setTimeout` to schedule code to run after a certain number of milliseconds, or with '0' when the current execution path and pending events are handled by the javascript runtime:

```
  doSomething(): void {
    this.isLoading = true  // never shows
    this.expensiveOperation() // completes executing before updating UI
    this.isLoading = false // when this function ends, isLoading is still false
  }
  
  doSomethingAsync(): void{
    this.isLoading = true
    setTimeout(() => { // let UI process changes, then do work
      this.expensiveOperation()
      this.isLoading = false
    }, 0)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.isLoading = false;
```

needs to be at the end of the promise/observable subscribe: In your example, this.isLoading = true is directly followed by = false because you are not waiting for the end of the promise to do that assigment.

```
// operation lasting around 1 second
```

is asynch code. Look how to handle promise/Observable in JS to understand the concept.